# How can I use gulp to replace a string in a file?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-concat, gulp-replace

I am using gulp to uglify and make ready my javascript files for production. What I have is this code:

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var del = require('del');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gzip = require('gulp-gzip');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

var js = {
    src: [
        // more files here
        'temp/js/app/appConfig.js',
        'temp/js/app/appConstant.js',
        // more files here
    ],

gulp.task('scripts', ['clean-js'], function () {
    return gulp.src(js.src).pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(concat('js.min.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('content/bundles/'))
      .pipe(gzip(gzip_options))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('content/bundles/'));
});
```

What I need to do is to replace the string:

```
dataServer: "http://localhost:3048",
```

with

```
dataServer: "http://example.com",
```

In the file 'temp/js/app/appConstant.js',

I'm looking for some suggestions. For example perhaps I should make a copy of the appConstant.js file, change that (not sure how) and include appConstantEdited.js in the js.src?

But I am not sure with gulp how to make a copy of a file and replace a string inside a file.

Any help you give would be much appreciated.

Comment: try with [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace) or maybe the best fit would be [gulp-environments](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-environments)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Gulp streams input, does all transformations, and then streams output. Saving temporary files in between is AFAIK non-idiomatic when using Gulp.

Instead, what you're looking for, is a streaming-way of replacing content. It would be moderately easy to write something yourself, or you could use an existing plugin. For me, [`gulp-replace`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace) has worked quite well.

If you want to do the replacement in all files it's easy to change your task like this:

```
var replace = require('gulp-replace');

gulp.task('scripts', ['clean-js'], function () {
    return gulp.src(js.src)
      .pipe(replace(/http:\/\/localhost:\d+/g, 'http://example.com'))
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(concat('js.min.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('content/bundles/'))
      .pipe(gzip(gzip_options))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('content/bundles/'));
});
```

You could also do `gulp.src` just on the files you expect the pattern to be in, and stream them seperately through `gulp-replace`, merging it with a `gulp.src` stream of all the other files afterwards.

Answer (score 10):

You may also use module [gulp-string-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-string-replace) which manages with regex, strings or even functions.

**Example:**

**Regex:**

```
var replace = require('gulp-string-replace');

gulp.task('replace_1', function() {
  gulp.src(["./config.js"]) // Every file allown. 
    .pipe(replace(new RegExp('@env@', 'g'), 'production'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/config.js'))
});
```

**String:**

```
gulp.task('replace_1', function() {
  gulp.src(["./config.js"]) // Every file allown. 
    .pipe(replace('environment', 'production'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/config.js'))
});
```

**Function:**

```
gulp.task('replace_1', function() {
  gulp.src(["./config.js"]) // Every file allown. 
    .pipe(replace('environment', function () {
       return 'production';
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/config.js'))
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that the most correct solution is to use the [gulp-preprocess](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-preprocess) module. It will perform the actions you need, depending on the variable `PRODUCTION`, defined or not defined during the build.

**Source code:**

```
/* @ifndef PRODUCTION */
dataServer: "http://localhost:3048",
/* @endif */
/* @ifdef PRODUCTION **
dataServer: "http://example.com",
/* @endif */
```

**Gulpfile:**

```
let preprocess = require('gulp-preprocess');
const preprocOpts = {
  PRODUCTION: true
};

gulp.task('scripts', ['clean-js'], function () {
  return gulp.src(js.src)
    .pipe(preprocess({ context: preprocOpts }))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(concat('js.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('content/bundles/'));
}
```

This is the best solution because it allows you to control the changes that are made during the build phase.

Answer (score 3):

There I have a versioning specific example for your reference.
let say you have version.ts file and it contains the version code inside it. You now can do as the follows:

```
gulp.task ('version_up', function () {
    gulp.src (["./version.ts"])
        .pipe (replace (/(\d+)\.(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))?(?:\-(\w+))?/, process.env.VERSION))
        .pipe (gulp.dest ('./'))
});
```

the above regex works for many situation on any conventional version formats.